# read a hex file that is burned on msp430F169 microcontroller

Tags: msp430, hexdump

I have a program running on one of my msp430F169 microcontroller. 
I donot have the source code for the same.
 I had only the hex file that i used to burn and it is misplaced.
 So I just want to read this program (hex file) from this microcontrollers and burn it on another same microcontroller.
We use a Olimex Jtag tiny V2 programmer.
Is it possible to do so.? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you can still program the device (i.e. the flash protection fuse is not blown), you should also be able to read the flash. Perhaps Olimex documentation or their support forums could help.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It helped.